# Regex to match special list items

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have weird list of items and lists like this with `|` as a delimiters and `[[ ]]` as a parenthesis. It looks like this:

```
| item1 | item2 | item3 | Ulist1[[ | item4 | item5 | Ulist2[[ | item6 | item7 ]] | item8 ]] | item9 | list3[[ | item10 | item11 | item12 ]] | item13 | item14
```

I want to match items in lists called `Ulist*` (items 4-8) using RegEx and replace them with `Uitem*`. The result should look like this:

```
| item1 | item2 | item3 | Ulist1[[ | Uitem4 | Uitem5 | Ulist2[[ | Uitem6 | Uitem7 ]] | Uitem8 ]] | item9 | list3[[ | item10 | item11 | item12 ]] | item13 | item14
```

I tryied almost everything I know about RegEx, but I haven't found any RegEx matching each item inside if the Ulists. My current RegEx:

```
/Ulist(\d+)\[\[(\s*(\|\s*[^\s\|]*)*\s*)*\]\]/i
```

What is wrong? I am beginner with RegEx.

It is in Python 2.7, specifically my code is:

```
    def fixDirtyLists(self, text):
        text = textlib.replaceExcept(text, r'Ulist(\d+)\[\[(\s*(\|\s*[^\s\|]*)*\s*)*\]\]', r'Ulist\1[[ U\3 ]]', '', site=self.site)
        return text
```

`text` gets that weird list, `textlib` replaces RegEx with RegEx. Not complicated at all.

Comment: You've already asked this question before, and it got deleted. Why do you ask again ?

Comment: Add your pice of code, where this RE is used, please

Comment: I've never asked here before. Piece of code added and question updated

Comment: Did you try PyPi regex module? It supports recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (with Python 2.7.9+ it can be done by a mere `pip install regex` when in `\Python27\Scripts\` folder), you will be able to match nested square brackets. You can match the strings you need, replace `item` with `Uitem` inside only those substrings.

The pattern (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yB3yO6/1), note that PyPi regex recursion resembles that of PCRE):

```
(Ulist\d+)(\[\[(?>[^][]|](?!])|\[(?!\[)|(?2))*]])
^-Group1-^^-----------Group2--------------------^
```

A short explanation: `(Ulist\d+)` is Group 1 that matches a literal word `Ulist` followed by 1 or more digits followed by `(\[\[(?>[^][]|](?!])|\[(?!\[)|(?2))*]])` that matches substrings starting with `[[`  up to the corresponding `]]`.

And the Python code:

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = "| item1 | item2 | item3 | Ulist1[[ | item4 | item5 | Ulist2[[ | item6 | item7 ]] | item8 ]] | item9 | list3[[ | item10 | item11 | item12 ]] | item13 | item14"
>>> pat = r'(Ulist\d+)(\[\[(?>[^][]|](?!])|\[(?!\[)|(?2))*]])'
>>> res = regex.sub(pat, lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2).replace("item", "Uitem"), s)
>>> print(res)
| item1 | item2 | item3 | Ulist1[[ | Uitem4 | Uitem5 | Ulist2[[ | Uitem6 | Uitem7 ]] | Uitem8 ]] | item9 | list3[[ | item10 | item11 | item12 ]] | item13 | item14
```

To avoid modifying `list`s inside `Ulist`, use

```
def repl(m):
    return "".join([x.replace("item", "Uitem") if not x.startswith("list") else x for x in regex.split(r'\blist\d*\[{2}[^\]]*(?:](?!])[^\]]*)*]]', m.group(0))])
```

and replace the `regex.sub` with

```
res = regex.sub(pat, repl, s)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and I'll write, if it works for me or not, but it looks like great solution

Comment: There is a problem, when there is a `list` inside of an `Ulist`. I don't want to change items of that list to Uitems, because it is not an Ulist. Do you know, how to solve this?

Comment: It should be easier to process in a callback method. I need some time to check.

Comment: And could `x.replace()` or `m.group(2).replace()` functions replace regex too (in case of much more complicated item names)?

Comment: You can use a **`regex.sub(regex_pattern, replacement, input)`**.

Comment: So e.g. `x.replace()` changes to `x.regex.sub()`? And the final code with updated answer would look like [this](http://pastebin.com/6Z8kDjq0)?

Comment: `x.replace(old, new)` only uses regular string replacement. When using `re`/`regex`, you need `(re or regex).sub(regex_searching_for_old, pattern_replacement_with_new, x)`. I think the code at pastebin should work.

Comment: It works for `| item1 | item2 | item3 | Ulist1[[ | item4 | item5 | Ulist2[[ | item6 | item7 ]] | item8 ]] | item9 | list3[[ | item10 | item11 | item12 ]] | item13 | item14`, but if I modify it (to add a list inside of an Ulist), the script fails with error `Neoprávněný přístup do paměti (SIGSEGV) (core dumped [obraz paměti uložen])` (translation: unauthorized access to memory (SIGSEGV),  core dumped, memory image saved)

Comment: Modified list: `| item1 | item2 | item3 | Ulist1[[ | item4 | item5 | Ulist2[[ | item6 | item7 ]] | item8 | list4[[ | item15 | item16 | item17 ]] | item18 ]] | item9 | list3[[ | item10 | item11 | item12 ]] | item13 | item14`

Comment: I am afraid that it can be a bug in the regex module.

Comment: Does your machine produce the same error? Could you report it if you know, where? I'll try to apply the code to my real case (not simplified testing case) and we'll see

Comment: Also, please try to remove capturing groups since we are not interested in them if we use `repl`: `pat = r'Ulist\d+\[\[(?>[^][]|](?!])|\[(?!\[)|(?2))*]]'`.

Comment: I handled complicated cases by running modified script multiple times, so it is OK now. I have another similar list pattern, where I want to change `items` to `Uitems` in `Ulists`. I thought I could use the same solution for both, but it looks like I made a mistake when changing the code for the second case and I don't know, what's wrong. Please see [my question about the second case as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923554/regex-to-match-special-list-items-ii).

Comment: Isn't that "memory" bug caused by some mistype in the argument of `regex.split()`? For me the regex inside does not make sense unlike the one in `pat` (but I'm a beginner)

Comment: The regex inside `repl` is a good and very efficient regex based on an unroll-the-loop technique. There are no issues with the types I believe.

Comment: OK, then I hope they'll fix it somewhen. I also figured out the mistake in the second case, so I changed it and asked for help with that list inside Ulist issue

Comment: Running script multiple times finally didn't helped. I also tried to add a list inside an Ulist inside another Ulist and test the code for this case. Memory error didn't appeared, but the text wasn't processed, so the modified answer isnẗ still working.